# which Nav2 topic message changes when reached the goal?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using ROS2 humble navigation2 package.

I am now trying to check if the robot reached the goal by monitoring a specific topic.

I found out that the length of message which goes to  /plan topic reduces as it gets closer to the target goal.

But I'd like to ask if there's better way to find out whether it reached a goal or not. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417628/which-nav2-topic-message-changes-when-reached-the-goal?/) by [kenloumixx](https://answers.ros.org/users/126519/kenloumixx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2023-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be using Nav2's action interface to request navigation commands which will provide you with feedback and ultimately a result once navigation is complete. You should not be monitoring topics or hacking into action server's internal topics.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Comment: Which action interface would it be? nav2_msgs/action/NavigateToPose has std_msgs/Empty as result... (Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to make a comment)